# How to call phtml of custom module in my custome theme layout Magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2.2, theme-overriding

Help me to get the content written in **custom `phtml`** of the **`custom module`** to my **`custom theme`**.

I have custom theme `Customtheme_Sample`, which is having custom layout `customhome.xml`.

And I have the custom module `Showcase_Newitems`, here I have `helloworld.phtml` in templates. Now, I need to call `helloworld.phtml` from `customhome.xml`.

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you update your codes?

Comment: How you are accessing the page to which this layout file `customehome.xml` belongs. Is this a controller or something else?

Comment: accept my answer if it solved your problem:)

Answer (score 8):

try this in your layout file (customhome.xml)

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Customtheme\Sample\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2, you should not use your module's templates in the theme file anymore (like back in Magento 1). Instead, your module directory should contain the code and the view files.

In your module directory, add the directory `view/frontend/layout`. Then, add the correct layout file for the scope. You won't use `customhome.xml`. I assume you want to add something to the homepage, so simply create a file with the name `cms_index_index.xml`.

Then add the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Myname\Mymodule\Block\Myblockname" name="customhome" template="Myname_Mymodule::customhome.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

The filename (`cms_index_index.xml`) determines where your content is shown (you don't use different layout handles inside the same XML file anymore). So, if you want to show it on every page, the file should be named `default.xml`; if you want to show it on product pages, the file should be named `catalog_product_view.xml`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/Customtheme/sample/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

You call your phtml in your container like this:

```
<block class="Showcase\Newitems\Block\{BlockName}" name="helloworld.mod" template="Showcase_Newitems::helloworld.phtml" />
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? the one who did it, be brave and he explains to me why ?